# How to choose order and cut-off frequency for low-pass Butterworth filter?

Tags: sensors, acceleration, electronic-filters

When using IMU data (accelerations and angular velocities), many papers use a 4th order low-pass butterworth filter with a cutoff frequency of 5 Hz. However, none of them really justify why those filters have been chosen.

Can anyone please explain how the order and cutoff frequency are chosen for a filter of this nature? My data has a sampling frequency of 125 Hz